# hdfs ls on directory returns No such file or directory error

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

HDFS ls on below two directories returning No such file or directory error.

```
[mybox]$ hdfs dfs -ls /data/tdc/dv1/corp/base/dpp/raw/load_date=2018-05-01/ | grep Tenant
drwxr-xr-x   - tdcdv1r tdcdv1c          0 2018-05-01 18:28 /data/tdc/dv1/corp/base/dpp/raw/load_date=2018-05-01/rtng_ky=Access.NBNOrder.Amend.Info.{Tenant}.Rejected.v2.event
drwxr-xr-x   - tdcdv1r tdcdv1c          0 2018-05-01 15:35 /data/tdc/dv1/corp/base/dpp/raw/load_date=2018-05-01/rtng_ky=Access.NBNOrder.Amend.Info.{Tenant}.v2.event
```

See the error:

```
[mybox]$ hdfs dfs -ls /data/tdc/dv1/corp/base/dpp/raw/load_date=2018-05-01/rtng_ky=Access.NBNOrder.Amend.Info.{Tenant}.Rejected.v2.event
ls: `/data/tdc/dv1/corp/base/dpp/raw/load_date=2018-05-01/rtng_ky=Access.NBNOrder.Amend.Info.{Tenant}.Rejected.v2.event': No such file or directory
```

I am not able to understand. Its a directory, it should return the content but its returning error.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the weird characters ({ and }) in the path:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /data/tdc/dv1/corp/base/dpp/raw/load_date=2018-05-01/rtng_ky=Access.NBNOrder.Amend.Info.\\{Tenant\\}.Rejected.v2.event
```

**EDIT**
As in the comments said you can comment the path to avoid escape the weird characters.
This should work fine:

```
 hdfs dfs -ls '/data/tdc/dv1/corp/base/dpp/raw/load_date=2018-05-01/rtng_ky=Access.NBNOrder.Amend.Info.{Tenant}.Rejected.v2.event'
```

Comment: What if i am doing a recursive ls on the parent directory `data/tdc/dv1/corp/base/dpp/raw/load_date=2018-05-01/`, it will through error. dosen't it auto detect the special characeter and avoid error.?, I think this is bug in hdfs.

Comment: As far as i know. Mannually escaping them is the only way. At least with the hdfs dfs. With the Java client you may be able manage it better

Comment: You should be able to quote them `ls '/data/{{path}}'`